# Could not found FtpWebRequest in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, ftpwebrequest

I am uploading one **XML** file to web server using **FTP**

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Append, myIsolatedStorage))
            {
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri"ftp://" + IPServer + "/" + isoStream.Name));
                reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("uname", "pass");
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;


                int bufferLength = 2048;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

                Stream uploadStream = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();
                int contentLength = isoStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

                while (contentLength != 0)
                {
                    uploadStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    contentLength = isoStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                }
            }
```

But I could not found **FtpWebRequest**. I have also added assembly **System.Net**. I am not getting What is the issue ? Can anyone help me to solve this? Can I upload the file by using **FtpWebRequest** in windows phone ? Is my code is correct to upload a file or not ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) in Windows Phone as of right now.

The same question asked [elsewhere](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/3fed4795-341e-4fb6-ba78-29e4a7ee3db3/ftpwebrequest) caused people to mention using a service that wraps FTP calls in HTTP. That appears to be your only option right now unless you find some third-party component to use.

Comment: Hey Tim, Thank you for reply. Then how can I upload file on ftp server?

Comment: I edited my answer with a bit more info. Sorry I don't have much in the way of help. Just doesn't seem too easy right now.

Comment: Ok I will try by using HTTP